# Dell xps 13" font not big enough

Tags: themes, fonts

i am trying to have a descent reading experience using Dell XPS 13" at 2560x1600px.
Is there a uniform solution to adjust the fonts allover or i need to edit the settings in each app?
I am struggling to increase the font size in Thunderbird for example.
Is there some Theme that takes care of such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. In "Settings - Display", you can set the scale. This will change the size of all on-screen elements. Currently, scaling is done best in integers. While you can turn on "Fractional scaling"  to scale also with fractions, turning that on requires processing power of the computer and thus goes at the expense of graphics performance.
2. Besides, you also can change only the font scale. The setting is not exposed, but you can access the setting when you install "Tweaks". On the "Fonts" tab, you can set a scaling factor. That setting will have effect in most applications, but not in applications that use specific toolkits.

It is probably best to first experience whether a combination of scaling and font scaling can provide an appearance that pleases you. Alternatively, fractional scaling will certainly allow you to find a good setting, but then you will need to accept a potential decrease in system performance.

Comment: thanks @vanadium. I have tried all this but I get this issue that the fonts in some cases exceed the container they are supposed to fit in. I can see this in some settings screens or the web developer tools in firefox or Thunderbird.